How can I get a Viewport render using GPU's connected to the internet?
I'm trying to get a viewport render of my .blend file by connecting to an external GPU online but so far the only solutions I found were for rendering entire images instead of rendering a quick preview of the scene on the blender viewport. Are there any ways to make this happen?
